# Will Google revoke my AdSense approval if I modify the design of my website?

Tags: google-adsense

I need to modify my website's design to make the UI simpler and better looking.

If I modify my site's look and feel, is there a chance that Google will revoke the site's eligibility for Google AdSense? We worked very hard to make our site eligible for AdSense.

Answer (score 1):

The way that you're talking about changing your site, if anything Google would ***support***.

By improving your website's UX, you are increasing the likelihood that potential customers of Google's clients' will have a pleasant Ad experience.

Adsense might even give you a cookie.

*I couldn't help myself...sorry*

As long as doing so doesn't mess with the actual Adsense code, or modify content in a way that violates the [Adsense publisher policy](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10502938), you're fine.

> **Don't tamper with the AdSense code.**
>
> Once you've generated your code, we ask that you do not alter any portion of the code or change the layout, behavior, targeting, or delivery of ads for any reason, unless specifically authorized to do so by Google.

Full list: [Adsense Policies: Beginners Guide](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/23921)

Despite the rather absolute verbiage of the above guideline, there *are* some things you can do. For example, in the spirit of improving your UX, you may also be interested in implementing [Responsive Ad Units](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9183362).

[image]